# Throwable constructors

Tags: java, exception, constructor, throwable

The 4 types of `Throwable constructors` are :-

> Throwable() :
>   Constructs a new throwable with null as its detail message.
>
> Throwable(String message) :
>   Constructs a new throwable with the specified detail message.
>
> Throwable(String message, Throwable cause) :
>   Constructs a new throwable with the specified detail message and cause.
>
> Throwable(Throwable cause) :
>   Constructs a new throwable with the specified cause and a detail message of (cause==null ? null : cause.toString())

In a piece of code, the first two constructors types are working properly, but the other two are reporting compile time error.

```
IOException e = new IOException();  //Working properly

ArithmeticException ae = new ArithmeticException("Top Layer");  //Working properly

ArithmeticException ae = new ArithmeticException("Top Layer", e);  //Not working

ArithmeticException ae = new ArithmeticException(e);  //Not working
```

The last two declarations are reporting error

> No suitable constructors found for ArithmeticException

I am using JDK 8

Why the last two declarations are reporting error?
Also how do I make them work?

Comment: A subclass is able to provide completely different constructors, i.e. `ArithmeticException` does just not provide those two, which is fine.

Comment: @Thomas : pls post an answer with correction in my code

Comment: Well, seems you got your answer already. :) Besides that the correct would be to just remove the lines that you marked as not working, since those constructors simply don't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `ArithmeticException` is a **unchecked exceptions** and from [RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)

> RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions. **Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause** if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary.

From [ArithmeticException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html)

there is no constructor as below thats why its giving you compile time error:

```
AithmeticException ae = new ArithmeticException("Top Layer", e);  //Not working
ae = new ArithmeticException(e);  //Not working
```

Better use [RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) for this:

```
RuntimeException ae = new RuntimeException("Top Layer", e);  
ae = new RuntimeException(e);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the JavaDoc for ArithmeticException

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html

You will see:

> Constructor and Description
>
> ArithmeticException() Constructs an
> ArithmeticException with no detail message. ArithmeticException(String
> s) Constructs an ArithmeticException with the specified detail
> message.

So none of theses constructor are implemented:

```
Throwable(String message, Throwable cause) : Constructs a new throwable with the specified detail message and cause.

Throwable(Throwable cause) : Constructs a new throwable with the specified cause and a detail message of (cause==null ? null : cause.toString())
```